# ISO Calendar week number

Tags: python

I am trying to generate week number for 12 weeks from today like weekly wise and i am seeing last 53 week is missing ..

ISO calendar week 2022-Jan-1 is giving week number 52

```
from datetime import datetime
current_dateTime = datetime.now()
temp_n=12
def week_num_gen():
    
        num=0
        global wknum_gen
        wknum_gen=[]
        for i in range(0,temp_n):

            if i==0 :
#                 Weeknum7 = date.today() + timedelta(days=2)
                Weeknum7=datetime(current_dateTime.year, 1,1)
#             if i==0 and current_dateTime.year==2023:
# #                 Weeknum7 = date.today() + timedelta(days=2)
          
            else:
                Weeknum7 = Weeknum7 + timedelta(days=7)
            wknum_gen.append(Weeknum7.isocalendar().week)
            num=num+7

week_num_gen()
wklist_1=list(wknum_gen)
wklist_1
```

result is below
[52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

expected is result is below
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12]

and if i try to generate it from today for 12 weeks

```
Weeknum7=datetime(current_dateTime.year, 11,2)
```

result is below with error

[44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3]
next 12 weeks
expected result is [ 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,1, 2,3]

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but weeks don't line up cleanly to years. ISO starts the week on Monday and ends it on Sundays and numbers them according to the year in which the starting Monday lands. So if you are legit wanting the iso calendar week, then your result is correct as Jan 1st 2022 was in the 52nd week of 2021. This year also has 52 weeks and that last week ends on Jan 1st 2023.

Comment: That being said, since you aren't looking for ISO weeks using their definition, how are you defining weeks? What weekday is the start and end of your week and how do you handle the start and end of the year precisely. Your definition will then guide how to code this.

Comment: Thank you .. actually the week containing January 1 is the first week of the year, and is numbered week 1 all the way upto last december last week

Comment: is there any efficient way to get expected result would be a great help